# MousePressed commands after resizing the app

Tags: java, resize, mouseevent

Since the x and y positions change everytime you resize the app.
How would I manage to use the **MousePressed** commands after resizing the application(for example going from fullscreen to windowed mode, and in reverse)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You get the screen size and divide it by the X/Y position, which gives you a ratio. Worked for me on 2 monitors(both 16:9), I do not know how it will work with other resolutions. Hope it helps